# how to play video from sub folder of assets folder in android

Tags: android, android-videoview, assets

I am trying to play video from sub-folder's of Assets folder.

I have created one folder xyz in assets folder.

this is my code:

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/assets/xyz/"+"age.mp4";
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    // videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.setMediaController(null);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

But it is giving me error  `E/MediaPlayer(11068): error (1, -2147483648)`

also tried this code:

```
public void Play(String fileName) {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;
        try {

            String[] array = getApplicationContext().getAssets().list("long_a");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "file is exists  " + array.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            descriptor = getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd(
                    "xyz/say.mp4");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
        long end = descriptor.getLength();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start,
                    end);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/assets/xyz/"+"age.mp4";
```

with this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("xyz/age.mp4");
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

**and make sure you get ID of video view from layout like:**

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
```

**Create MediaController like:**

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);  
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
```

**Set MediaController like:**

```
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Comment: I tried using this but it's not working for me. giving same error :(

Comment: VideoView does not accept AssetsFileDescriptor as parameter. And also "file://android_asset/" URI shema too

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("test/xyz/AudioFile.mp4");
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

Comment: He's using VideoView not mediaplayer.

Comment: assets path is same for both

Comment: Its not same. VideoView does not accept AssetsFileDescriptor as parameter. And also "file://android_asset/" URI shema too